# How to create an empty list of dictionaries and populate afterwords?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, random

I need to initialize an empty List of Dictionary(LOD) which must have the following keys in it. `"id","name","age", "gender"`. I want to create a loop/nested loop that starts populating the LOD. For poppulating I have a list which has ID's and the rest of the keys are generated using the random function.
The ID list looks like this: `id = ['1','2','3']`

The result must look something like this.

```
LOD = [
      {  
          'id': '1',
          'name':'122121',
          'age':'2131',
          'gender':'121' 

       },
       {  
          'id': '2',
          'name':'122121',
          'age':'2131',
          'gender':'121' 

       },
{  
          'id': '3',
          'name':'122121',
          'age':'2131',
          'gender':'121' 

       },
       ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CJDB already does what you want. But if you'd perhaps prefer another approach:

```
ids = ['1','2','3']
keys = ["name","age", "gender"]
LOD = []
```

and then populate your list with dictionaries

```
for i in ids:
    your_dictionary = {"id": i}
    for key in keys:
        your_dictionary[key] = '{}_rnd_function_output'.format(key)
    LOD.append(your_dictionary)
```

And the output would be

```
>>> LOD

[{'id': '1',
  'name': 'name_rnd_function_output',
  'age': 'age_rnd_function_output',
  'gender': 'gender_rnd_function_output'},
 {'id': '2',
  'name': 'name_rnd_function_output',
  'age': 'age_rnd_function_output',
  'gender': 'gender_rnd_function_output'},
  {'id': '3',
   'name': 'name_rnd_function_output',
   'age': 'age_rnd_function_output',
   'gender': 'gender_rnd_function_output'}
]
```

You might consider having a sub-dictionaries within a dictionary. Your ids would be keys for main dictionary and sub-dictionaries would be values.

```
LOD = {}
for i in ids:
    LOD[i] = {}
    for key in keys:
        LOD[i][key] = '{}_rnd_function_output'.format(key)
```

And the output

```
>>> LOD
{'1': {'name': 'name_rnd_function_output',
       'age': 'age_rnd_function_output',
       'gender': 'gender_rnd_function_output'},
 '2': {'name': 'name_rnd_function_output',
       'age': 'age_rnd_function_output',
       'gender': 'gender_rnd_function_output'},
 '3': {'name': 'name_rnd_function_output',
       'age': 'age_rnd_function_output',
       'gender': 'gender_rnd_function_output'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary-comprehension for this:

```
ids = ['1','2','3']

LOD = [
      {  
          'id': i,
          'name':'122121',
          'age':'2131',
          'gender':'121' 

       } for i in ids
       ]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> LOD
[{'id': '1', 'name': '122121', 'age': '2131', 'gender': '121'},
 {'id': '2', 'name': '122121', 'age': '2131', 'gender': '121'},
 {'id': '3', 'name': '122121', 'age': '2131', 'gender': '121'}]
```

Or, using the random module:

```
import random

ids = ['1','2','3']

LOD = [
      {  
          'id': i,
          'name': str(random.randint(100000, 999999)),
          'age': str(random.randint(1000, 9999)),
          'gender': str(random.randint(100, 999)) 
       } for i in ids
       ]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> LOD
[{'id': '1', 'name': '727325', 'age': '5367', 'gender': '238'},
 {'id': '2', 'name': '316019', 'age': '8963', 'gender': '702'},
 {'id': '3', 'name': '464023', 'age': '4324', 'gender': '155'}]
```

Note that you should not use `id` as a variable name as it shadows the builtin python `id` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by initializing `dict` objects in list comprehensions

```
keys = ['id', 'name', 'age', 'gender']
ids = ['1', '2', '3']
LOD = [dict((key, i if key == 'id' else random.randint(1, 100)) for key in keys) for i in ids]

print(LOD)
'''
[{'id': '1', 'name': 34, 'age': 10, 'gender': 57},
{'id': '2', 'name': 64, 'age': 13, 'gender': 21},
{'id': '3', 'name': 11, 'age': 17, 'gender': 2}]
'''
```